# Can "playing on your ..." be used as a phrase indicating what the trick is playing with?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-usage

I know that we can say about an illusion that it' "playing on your mind". Could we describe a con artist as someone who is *playing on your confidence*?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I was under the impression that the idiom contained the word "tricks", as in "my mind's playing **tricks** on me". (There's a chance you are mixing it up with "**preying** on your mind**, which has a different meaning.) Therefore, I don't think "playing on your confidence" is idiomatic. However, in context it would probably be understood.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

*Con man* is a short version of *confidence man*, or, one who plays *confidence schemes*.

In other words, they play [a trick/scam/scheme] based on someone's confidence.

Comment: He wasn't asking about the derivation of "con man", and a yes/no answer doesn't really help anyone else.  And it's hard to take your answer seriously when it contains multiple grammatical errors.

Comment: @stangdon Sometimes, the simplest answer is correct.  And this answer is 100% correct..  As for the 'grammatical errors' just point them out so they can be fixed.  That's better for everyone.  Such downvotes don't help anyone.

Comment: @stangdon Yes, that's what I'm after.